# which redis data type fits for charts

Tags: types, redis

I'd like to store data in redis so I can save and pull quickly without using my sql database

most charts are made of a bunch of number, usually by time

an example key would be

```
chart_type:date:user_id
```

if I use a sorted set by date then I don't know (yet) if I can grab values from 2 weeks ago until now. A hash doesn't seem to fit as well (or does it? Im not sure)

I've tried to understand which data type is best used for this case, but I have yet to get this from the docs

Comment: What constitutes a point in the chart? It is just a number value, or is there a time component for each number as well?

Comment: a point is just a number - like how many users entered on a given day

Comment: So a point is not _just_ a number, it has a date with it, right? You can use sorted sets for this, want to see an example?

Comment: yes an example would be excellent. But after I save a the sorted set, how do I fetch the values between 2 given dates, in one request?